# How to set up/monitor huge amounts of equivalent DAGs

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new to Airflow and am still learning the concepts.

I am trying to monitor a huge amount of webpages (>1000) once a day.
At the moment I dynamically create a single DAG for each webpage (data acquisition and processing). This works from a functional point of view. However, looking at the User-Interface I find the amount of DAGs overwhelming and my question is:

1. Is this the right way to do it? (a single DAG for each webpage)
2. Is there any way to get a better overview of how the monitoring of all webpages is doing?

Since all DAGs are equivalent and only deal with a different url, it made me think that grouping these DAGs together or having a common overview might be possible or at least a good idea.
E.g. if the acquisition or processing of a certain webpage is failing I would like to see this easily in the UI without having to scroll many pages to find a certain DAG.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have one DAG and have multiple tasks. Based on information you provided, the only thing that seem to change is the URL, so better have one DAG and have many tasks.

Comment: I thought about doing this but didn't find any documentation with a principle that led me to do so. Do you have any documentation/article that has a little bit more explanation when to combine the tasks in one DAG and when to split them?

Comment: Generally for me, if the tasks are related, needs to be executed under the same schedule, take almost the same parameters except for 1-2 (which in your cases is different webpage or URL) then you should use a single DAG. Makes it easy to manage and monitor.